# How to make stripe.createToken() work without using <CardElement /> from react-stripe-elements?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, stripe-payments

I guess there are two parts to my questions. What I am trying to do is that I want to use redux-form with custom validations and pass data to stripe on the frontend and get a token.

1) What do I pass into createToken() from stripe if I don't want to use its input elements?

2) Is there a way to make redux-form work with react-stripe-elements?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

By design, `react-stripe-elements` requires that you use the Stripe-provided input components, such as `CardElement`. Parsing and validation of credit card numbers, expiration date, etc. in `CardElement` is handled by the library itself, and the raw input values themselves (e.g. `{ cardNumber: 1234567890 }`) are inaccessible to the rest of the app. In other words, there is no way to access a `cardNumber` prop from `CardElement`, and insert it into your redux store, for instance. To answer your first question, the API does not provide a means to explicitly pass your own credit card props, for example, `cardNumber`, to `createToken` in this case.

Stripe states this requirement in their documentation on Stripe Elements: 
https://stripe.com/docs/recipes/elements-react#create-token

> You can make use of Stripe Elements, our pre-built UI components, to create a payment form that securely collects your customer’s card information **without requiring you to handle sensitive card data.**

Also, check this issue for more details on why Stripe is requiring developers to make use of their pre-built components: https://github.com/stripe/react-stripe-elements/issues/19

A quote from @atty-stripe, one of the developers of `react-stripe-elements`:

> To maintain the simplest level of PCI compliance, Elements renders form inputs within iframes, while allowing complete customization using Stripe.js v3 APIs. As such, we highly recommend you use Stripe.js v3 and Elements to build your credit card form.